# Пустой столбец в TableView javafx

Tags: javafx, tableview, таблицы

Подскажите, возможно ли скрыть этот пустой столбец в таблице справа?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
tableView.setColumnResizePolicy(TableView.CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY);
```